# need patindex to match a-zA-Z0-9./-#' and space

Tags: sql-server

I am cleaning up some data and would like to create a patindex that would reject any string contains any character(s) except for A-Za-z0-9./'-# and a space.

This rejects the special chars which should be allowed:

```
patindex  (  '%[^A-Z0-9a-z./'-# ]%',stringtobetested )
```

Should I be masking the special chars? The bad and/or good chars can appear multiple times in a given string.

So where stringtobetested is abc#D-EF should pass but abc*def should fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work... it just uses replace to get around your escaping problems.

```
declare @stringtobetested1 varchar(64) = 'abc#D-EF'
declare @stringtobetested2 varchar(64) = 'abc*def '


select 
    @stringtobetested1 string1
    ,replace(replace(replace(replace(@stringtobetested1,'''','#'),' ','#'),'/','#'),'.','#') string1changed
    ,@stringtobetested2 string2
    ,replace(replace(replace(replace(@stringtobetested2,'''','#'),' ','#'),'/','#'),'.','#') string2changed
    ,patindex('%[^A-Z0-9a-z#-]%',replace(replace(replace(replace(@stringtobetested1,'''','#'),' ','#'),'/','#'),'.','#')) 
    ,patindex('%[^A-Z0-9a-z#-]%',replace(replace(replace(replace(@stringtobetested2,'''','#'),' ','#'),'/','#'),'.','#'))
```

Comment: The four nested replaces means it can handle up to 4 # per string?

Comment: I'm just replacing the special characters with # is all... it will pass regardless if there is 1 # or 7 #

Comment: so why are they nested?

Comment: I'm replacing the . the space, the /  and the ' with a # so that the patindex will pick it up. i edited it to show you... notice the space was replaced with a # for string2

Comment: The nest is 1 replace for each character which is causing problems with the escape in patindex.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I created a solution that went through it one char at a time. I will compare your solution (which requires SQL Server to rescan the strings for each replace) vs mine which scans a given string once in TSQL. Of course SQL Server needs regex badly.

Answer (score 1):

This can all be done with a `PATINDEX`, you just need some syntax help:

```
WITH test AS (
  SELECT val
    FROM (VALUES ('abc#D-EF./ -'''), ('abc*def')) AS t (val)
)
SELECT
    input = t.val,
    result = IIF(PATINDEX('%[^A-Z0-9a-z./''# -]%', t.val) > 0, 'fails', 'passes')
  FROM test t;
```

First of all, the pattern itself is a string, and strings in T-SQL escape `'` by doubling it to `''`. Secondly, inside a `[^ ]` wildcard in a pattern, the `-` is used to define a character range when it occurs between two characters. By moving it to an end of the wildcard pattern, it is treated literally.

Other escape sequences specific to pattern wildcards can be found in this docs page: [Pattern Matching in Search Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187489(v=sql.90)#searching-for-wildcard-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Please run more testing for my query, and adjust max string length to fit your requirement.

```
DECLARE @TestString varchar(64) = 'abc#D-E/*F'
, @MaxStringLen INT = 20


;WITH cte AS(SELECT 1 number
        UNION ALL
        SELECT number + 1 
        FROM cte 
        WHERE number < @MaxStringLen
)

SELECT @TestString AS OriginalString
    , CAST(CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(@TestString, Number, 1)
                    FROM cte
                    WHERE Number <= LEN(@TestString) AND
                        SUBSTRING(@TestString, Number, 1) LIKE '%[A-Z0-9a-z-# ./'']%' FOR XML Path(''))
                    AS xml) AS varchar(MAX)) AS ConvertedString
, CASE WHEN @TestString = CAST(CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(@TestString, Number, 1)
                    FROM cte
                    WHERE Number <= LEN(@TestString) AND
                        SUBSTRING(@TestString, Number, 1) LIKE '%[A-Z0-9a-z-# ./'']%' FOR XML Path(''))
                    AS xml) AS varchar(MAX))
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsAllowed
```